# Java Socket "Connection timed out: connect"

Tags: java, sockets, server, router, portforwarding

I'm running the Java example `KnockKnockServer` [1] on my Windows 7 machine on port `4242`. When I try to connect using the corresponding client, with `127.0.0.1:4242` as server ip/port, the client connects just fine. If I try with my (external) IP address however, I get the following error after several seconds of waiting:

`Connection timed out: connect` from a thrown `IOException` when executing

```
final Socket kkSocket = new Socket("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", 4242);
```

Of course I configured my router (`WISPR - NET1 2.44 (Aug 07 2012 - SVN: 7300)`) beforehand to forward the port `4242` to my machine. I tested the port forwarding using several online port scanners, e.g. [2]. Not only did the port scanner tell me that the port is open, I also saw on my server console output that a client had connected.

Unfortenately, I have no idea where the problem lies, or even if it has to do anything with Java or not. (Hence the Java example server to get familiar with Java server development.) I would really appreciate some help! Thank You!

**Update**: When running the server on Win7,

`telnet 127.0.0.1 4242` works on Win7

`telnet 192.168.1.109 4242` works on Win7 as well as a Macbook in the same network

`telnet 87.XXX.XXX.XXX 4242` (external ip) works neither on Win7 nor on Macbook, even though using the online port scanner with the same IP and port works (and the server recognizes that the port scanner connected).

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

[2] http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/

Comment: looks like a firewall issue

Comment: I tried deactivating/activating the default Win7 firewall, but it didn't fix the problem. The router I don't know what else I would change in the configuration other then the port forwarding that seems to work according to the online port scanners. Would you say it's the router or the Win7 firewall? The only thing I found in the router is a "SPI Firewall", which I enabled/disabled, but didn't help.

Comment: i was thinking of the Windows' firewall. Did you try to connect to your service from an other computer on the same network ?

Comment: I tried having the server on a Macbook Pro, and connecting to it from Win7 (and vice versa), but it just doesn't work.. :/ (Connection timed out)

Comment: Does your server listen on 0.0.0.0:4242 and not on 127.0.0.1:4242 ? you can see that with a netstat

Comment: `TCP    0.0.0.0:4242          MY-PC:0            LISTENING`
Is that now good or bad?

Comment: It's good, it means that it accepts connection from all sources. I don't see what is the culprit here. If the firewall is turned off, you should be able to connect to the server. Have you tried to telnet to your server (```telnet %server_ip% 4242```) from the other computer ? If it works, there is a problem in your code. If it doesn't, there is a problem on your network

Comment: I updated my question with some `telnet` experiments. Using telnet with the external IP doesn't seem to function at all. So I guess that means it has nothing to do with the Java code? Or at least not with the Java client..?

Comment: sometimes, using external IP fails due to some configuration on the local network (routers/firewalls... and it's another issue than port-forward) and sometimes it's by the ISP, you can't make a connection on your external IP, you need someone on another ISP or on another account (another external IP), that's why the online port scanner success, they are not on ur lan and not subscribers with ur ISP, if you can send the client-app to one of ur friends and ask them to start it

Comment: that's what i mean, https://superuser.com/questions/1047745/access-external-ip-from-inside-the-network it's router related issue

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will test accessing the server from the outside, but I guess that it's indeed the `hairpin` problem, because my router is not the most expensive one...